# Magento 2 - Add a message to a ko template that is created through a LayoutProcessorPlugin

Tags: magento2, plugin, knockoutjs

I need to add message "*Need it by today? Anything is possible, it's just a phone call away*"  in a KO template. However, this template is created through the `afterProcess` method `LayoutProcessPlugin.php` file.

I do not know how to modify the template so that I can add this messaging after the **Delivery Time Slots** field. Right now to get around that, I created a custom js file that appends a HTML element after the **Delivery Time Slots** field. However, the JS file is loading before the KO template finishing loading so doesn't append the message. I wrapped it around a 3 second `settimeout()` event, but I do not think this is the best way to do this. Below I included the php file that processes the layout (`LayoutProcessorPlugin.php`) and the custom JS file I created (`orderdeliverydate.js`).

File: `Bss/OrderDeliveryDate/Block/Plugin/Checkout/LayoutProcessorPlugin.php`

```
class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{
    protected $_helper;
    const DELIVERY_FORM_DISPLAY_AT_SHIPPING_ADDRESS = 0;
    const DELIVERY_FORM_DISPLAY_AT_SHIPPING_METHOD = 1;
    const DELIVERY_FORM_DISPLAY_AT_REVIEW_PAYMENTS = 2;

    public function __construct(
        \Bss\OrderDeliveryDate\Helper\Data $helper
        ) {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
    }

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {
        $container = null;
        if(!$this->_helper->isEnabled()) return $jsLayout;
        if($this->_helper->getDisplayAt() == self::DELIVERY_FORM_DISPLAY_AT_SHIPPING_ADDRESS) {
            $container = 'shipping-address-fieldset';
        } elseif($this->_helper->getDisplayAt() == self::DELIVERY_FORM_DISPLAY_AT_SHIPPING_METHOD) {
            $container = 'before-shipping-method-form';
        }

        if($this->_helper->getTimeSlot()){
            // before place order
            if($this->_helper->getDisplayAt() == self::DELIVERY_FORM_DISPLAY_AT_REVIEW_PAYMENTS){
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']['before-place-order']['children']['delivery_time_slot'] = [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
                        'id' => 'delivery-time-slot'
                    ],
                    'caption' => 'Please select delivery time slot',
                    'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.delivery_time_slot',
                    'label' => 'Delivery Time Slot',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'visible' => true,
                    'validation' => [],
                    'options' => $this->_helper->getTimeSlot(),
                    'sortOrder' => 201,
                    'id' => 'delivery-time-slot',
                ];
            }else{
                $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
                ['shippingAddress']['children'][$container]['children']['delivery_time_slot'] = [
                    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
                    'config' => [
                        'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                        'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/select',
                        'id' => 'delivery-time-slot'
                    ],
                    'caption' => 'Please select delivery time slot',
                    'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.delivery_time_slot',
                    'label' => 'Delivery Time Slot',
                    'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                    'visible' => true,
                    'validation' => [],
                    'options' => $this->_helper->getTimeSlot(),
                    'sortOrder' => 201,
                    'id' => 'delivery-time-slot',
                ];
            }
        }
        // before place order
        if($this->_helper->getDisplayAt() == self::DELIVERY_FORM_DISPLAY_AT_REVIEW_PAYMENTS){
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
            ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children']['before-place-order']['children']['shipping_arrival_comments'] = [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/textarea',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/textarea',
                    'id' => 'shipping-arrival-comments',
                    'rows' => 5
                ],
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.shipping_arrival_comments',
                'label' => 'Shipping Arrival Comment',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'visible' => true,
                'validation' => [],
                'sortOrder' => 202,
                'id' => 'shipping-arrival-comments'
            ];
        }else{
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children'][$container]['children']['shipping_arrival_comments'] = [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/textarea',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/textarea',
                    'id' => 'shipping-arrival-comments',
                    'rows' => 5
                ],
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.shipping_arrival_comments',
                'label' => 'Shipping Arrival Comment',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'visible' => true,
                'validation' => [],
                'sortOrder' => 202,
                'id' => 'shipping-arrival-comments'
            ];
        }
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

File: `MyVendor/OrderDeliveryDate/view/frontend/web/orderdeliverydate.js`

```
require([
    'jquery'
], function($) {
    'use strict';


    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log("I am getting executed");
        setTimeout(function()
        {
            console.log("In Timeout");
            if ($("div[name='shippingAddress.delivery_time_slot']").length) {
                console.log("It exists!");
                $("div[name='shippingAddress.delivery_time_slot']").after("<div class='field' id='delivery_time_sot_message'>Need it by today? Anything is possible, it's just a phone call away</div>");
            }
        }, 3000);




    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to do this is to make a copy of the file `Magento_Ui/view/frontend/web/templates/form/field.html` into your module under `{module_directory}/view/frontend/web/templates/form/`. You'll then insert your text element into this file somewhere towards the bottom.
Then modify the LayoutProcessorPlugin by replacing the occurrences of `ui/form/field` under the 'Delivery Time Slot' element with `Your_Module/form/field`.